# Pass environment variables to dependent targets in Makefile

Tags: makefile, continuous-integration

I have a Makefile in a project which roughly looks like the following:

```
.PHONY: lint test teamcity

lint:
    # commands here

test:
    # commands here

teamcity: lint test
```

The tools I'm running in `make lint` and `make test` are able to determine whether or not they are running in CI (TeamCity) by looking at `TEAMCITY_VERSION` environment variable.  However, we're running them in a Docker container on TeamCity agents, so the variable is not set.

I want to achieve the following:

1. When `make teamcity` is run, commands in `lint` and `test` targets must be run with `TEAMCITY_VERSION` set in the environment;
2. When `make test` or `make lint` are run, nothing special should happen (the variable must not be added, though it is not necessary to strip it if it is set in the outside environment).

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing the following:

```
.PHONY: lint test teamcity

lint:
    # commands here

test:
    # commands here

teamcity: export TEAMCITY_VERSION=1
teamcity: lint test
```

Here `TEAMCITY_VERSION` is declared as a target-specific variable, and the `export` directive exports it into the environment for prerequisite targets.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you?

```
.PHONY: lint test teamcity

lint:
    # commands here

test:
    # commands here

teamcity:
    $(MAKE) TEAMCITY_VERSION=<whatever> lint test
```

The second make invocation has `TEAMCITY_VERSION` set on the command line. So, for this second invocation the `TEAMCITY_VERSION` make variable will be set but also the `TEAMCITY_VERSION` shell environment variable for all recipes.

Comment: or add TEAMCITY_VERSION as a target-specific for the `teamcity` target and avoid the recursion?